# Retrieve products and sort Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm having a problem with my code currently it's loading the products but not accepting the order filter. here is what I have. Would appreciate any help.

```
 $_productCollection->clear()
               ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
               ->setPage($_GET['pageNo'],12)
               ->load()
               ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello check below code

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collection->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');

$products = $collection->load();